# High resolution CLI?

Tags: 10.10, command-line, grub2

I want the resolution of my console to match my screen resolution(1440x900). 1024x768 works fine but for some reason when I put 1440x900 when I switch to ttyX the command prompt is almost right off the bottom of the screen! The Ubuntu splash screen goes off the edge of the screen during boot as well.

Here is my /etc/default/grub

```
  4 GRUB_DEFAULT=0
  5 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  6 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  7 GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
  8 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
  9 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
 10 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
 11 GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900
 12 GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

How do I get my CLI resolution to be 1440x900?

Comment: Run `vbeinfo` to verify whether your hardware supports the resolution for the console.

Comment: I did. It says it supports 1440x900.

Comment: What video card are you using? With what driver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is something Kernel Mode Setting does for us automatically. KMS is a feature available for most of the open source graphics drivers. Basically, it means the system figures out the screen resolution as early as possible and sticks with it.

If you are willing to give up fancy 3D support and your graphics hardware has an open source driver available, you can try switching to that.

That's “nouveau,” as opposed to “nvidia,” for NVidia hardware.

“ati/radeon,” as opposed to “fglrx” for ATI hardware.

Comment: I'm thinking this is the answer in your particular case.  However, on natty with nvidia binary drivers - at least in my case - 1440x900 switching to a console works out of the box.  The text is fairly large, but it is still usable.  Wanting tiny text would mean I would have to go with open source drivers.  I KNOW it works with simple VESA drivers in knoppix for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you have to do to get Plymouth working with proprietary Nvidia drivers.

#### 1. Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file.

Open a terminal and run this command (you can paste it in):

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Uncomment this line (by removing the leading `#` character):

GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900

#### 2. Edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header`.

Run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

Find the line that says:

```
gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
```

Make a new line right after that line. The new line should say:

```
set gfxpayload=keep
```

#### 3. Update the GRUB2 configuration.

To apply the new GRUB configuration, simply run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Great - that was exactly what I was looking for.